# whitespace: nowrap for photo has issue when resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to display my photos horizontally, so i used

```
.stream {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.mod-pic {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.modelstream {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 90%; 
    width: auto;
}
```

for my photo's css

html looks like this: (I used javascript to render the photos)

```
<div class="stream">
        <div class="alexContainer"></div>
            <div class="template main alexTemplate">
                <div class="mod-pic">
                    <img class="pic modelstream" src="" alt=""/>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I resize the browser, the margin of the photo become too big, although
I want the photo to be responsive, but I don't want the margin between photo become too
big.
Can anyone help me to fix this problem? I would really appreciate it!
Thanks

Comment: i think margin-left takes percentages too? Set it as a percent of the element's container, and it should scale along when the container changes size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your container div/divs are becoming too wide when the window is re-sized. I think using CSS to set the [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) on one or more of the outer divs would solve your problem.

Comment: I set the margin just to avoid overlay with my nav bar, has nothing to do with the margin between each photos

Comment: Is there any other relevant CSS code that isn't currently included in the question?